# Return int[]-array or use own class for "Size"/"Dimension"/"Point"?

Tags: java

When a class of mine has a method which returns, for example, its current size which consists of a width and a height, or when I have a method that should return a point on the screen which consists of an x and a y value, what is the best approach to return this values?

Should I, which I doubt, just return a meaningless int[] or float[] array, which would be the easiest (and maybe fastest, if this noticeably affects the run time at all) way like this?

```
public int[] getPosition()
```

Or should I write an own little class with methods for getting and setting a width and a height / an x-coordinate and a y-coordinate?

```
public Dimension getSize()
```

As far as I have searched, there are no classes in the standard library which do exactly this.
Or are there?
I am not really sure whether [Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) and [Dimension](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html) are suitable for this tasks or if this would rather be a misuse of them.

What is the best approach to this, what is the best and most reasonable solution?

Thanks
David

Comment: Try to avoid arrays if possible and yes own model classes are appropriate (if you can't find existing classes which suits your case). You can use [Google Autovalue](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/14u_h-lMn7f1rXE1nDiLX0azS3IkgjGl5uxp5jGJ75RE/) to create nice model classes with generated `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` implementations.

Comment: I exptect `Point` and `Dimension` types to be even faster than arrays, especialy when accessing members. Array indexing needs runtime bound check.

Comment: Alright, thank to both of you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application, if you need just the x,y and the dimensions informations, using your own classes to represent Points and Dimensions is more appropriate than arrays (meaningless) and also than the java awt geom components (more complicated than your need). Create a Utility Classe in which you specify all what you need as generic component for the application.

Comment: Thank you, I've chosen yours as the accepted answer for pointing out that indeed an own class would be the best approach and that it should be prefered over using java's awt components.

Answer (score 1):

Use the more abstract terms!

In OOP, a clear level of abstraction is almost always good. This lets you and other people know what are you doing. Imagine this is your first time seeing this piece of code:

```
public int[] getSize ()
```

How would he/she know which element in the array stands for width or height? You can of course write comment

```
//0 index: width
//1 index: height
```

But maybe sometime later, you say you want to change the second element in array to width, and you forgot to change the comment.

See? Comments are easily outdated!

That's why you should create your own `Dimension` and `Point`.

```
public class Dimension {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    //getter setter omitted as I'm lazy. But please DO add them in your code!
}
```

Now imagine that this is your first time seeing this:

```
public Dimension getSize ()
```

And you go into the declaration of `Dimension` and see `width` and `height`. Even fools know that `Dimension.width` means the width of something.

As you can see now, **It's much more clearer now.**

Comment: Actually my main intention was to know whether I should create my own class for this or if there is any other way / which is the best other way around the int[] array, so, I certainly **know** I should not use the array and rather wanted to give it as a bad example that I want a better solution for, but I certainly did not make it that clear in my inital post, which is obviously not your fault!

I've marked Maouven's answer as the accepted answer, but nonetheless I appreciate your effort. :)